# DBIx::Class - where is this relationship being cached?

Tags: perl, dbix-class

I have an Order entity and an Address entity, and in my `Schema::Result::Order` module I have a simple belongs to relationship:

```
__PACKAGE__->belongs_to( "address", 'Schema::Result::Address', 
                                             { addressid => 'addressid' });
```

I run this code with `DBIC_TRACE=1`:

```
my $order = $schema->resulset('Order')->find($id);
my $add1 = $order->address;
my $add2 = $order->address;
```

and I only see one `SELECT ... FROM ADDRESS ...` query, so apparently the second `$order->address` method is not hitting the database.

So this might be a simple question, but where is the address object getting cached? (in the `$order` object?)

Secondly, is this caching configurable (i.e. can I configure DBIC to *not* cache these relationships)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the way you have your order to address relationship you will only have one address to the order:

```
__PACKAGE__->belongs_to( "address", 'Schema::Result::Address', 
                                            { addressid => 'addressid' });
```

If your order will have many addresses you will want:

```
__PACKAGE__->has_many( "address", 'Schema::Result::Address', 
                                            { addressid => 'addressid' });
```

Then you can retrieve the addresses a number of ways:

```
my $address_rs = $order->search_related('address',{});
while(my $row = $address_rs->next) {
#$row has an address record
}
```

I am not sure how the caching works in this situation

```
my $order = $schema->resulset('Order')->find($id);
my $add1 = $order->address;
my $add2 = $order->address;
```

But if you access your address record like this:

```
my $address_rs = $order->search_related('address',{});
```

you can control it with your query attributes:

https://metacpan.org/module/DBIx::Class::ResultSet#cache

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer: it's cached in `$order->{_relationship_data}->{address}`.

Haven't determined if that caching can be disabled.